# How to make cell references (E.g. !table1B3) auto change when moving data to new cell

Tags: excel, reference

So I have a list of team names. But if I was to add a new team to the list and put it into alphabetical order then any references to the team EG for example may now reference to the team Empire as the location for that data has now changed. Is there any easy way to make sure that the value being referenced to stays as the correct team even when re ordering or adding new values.

I hope its clear what my issue is, thanks. Here is the list so you have some context

- Alliance
- Arrow
- bvd.black
- DK
- EG
- Empire
- Execration
- Fnatic
- iG
- Infused
- Invasion
- MiTH
- Mski
- Na'vi
- Newbee
- Power Rangers (PR)
- Scythe
- Speed.cn
- Titan
- TongFu.W
- VG

Comment: Because I want data integrity, if I have it listed lots of time I could spell it wrong

Comment: True, how could I implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to name your existing range, say `rValid`, (or existing range plus some blanks to allow for later additions), select all the cells you want validated and in FILE > Data Tools - Data Validation, Data Validation...  Allow: List and for Source:

```
 =rValid
```

then OK.

[image: SO24408192 example]

Comment: I've named the existing list as a range leaving space at the end. But I don't understand how I use that to validate my other cells. I couldn't see how you could go from FILD to data tools and then data validation